# Not getting specific object using foreign key relationship in django

Tags: python, django, database, orm, artificial-intelligence

I am facing an issue where I'm trying to get an Egg item object by using foreign key relationship but it again and again show me this error

`Some Error Occurred While Saving Data: Egg matching query does not exist.`

My models are:

```
class SaleReturnItem(models.Model):
salereturn = models.ForeignKey(
    SaleReturn,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="salereturnitem"
)
saleReturnItemName=models.ForeignKey(Egg, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='salereturnitemegg',null=True)
saleReturnItemQuantity=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
saleReturnItemUnitPrice=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
saleReturnItemTotalAmount=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
saleReturnItemDiscount=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
saleReturnItemDiscountPrice=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)

class Egg(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(
    get_user_model(),
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1
)
eggName = models.TextField(null=True)
eggInSection = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='eggsection',default=1)
eggSalePrice = models.CharField(max_length=15,default=False)
eggPurchasePrice = models.CharField(max_length=15,default=False)
eggStockLimit = models.IntegerField(default=False)
eggStockQuantity = models.IntegerField(default=False)
eggInCategory = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='eggcategory',default=1)
eggExpiryDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
eggGst = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2,default=False)
```

and my view function is this

```
def saleReturn(request):
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('login')
elif request.user.userRole != 'admin':
    return render(request, 'pages/404.html')
else:
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            searchSaleInvoiceId = request.POST.get('searchSaleInvoice')
            searchSaleInvoice = SaleInvoice.objects.get(id=searchSaleInvoiceId)
            invoiceDateSaleReturn = request.POST.get('invoiceDateSaleReturn')

            saleReturnObject = SaleReturn(
                user=request.user,
                searchSaleInvoice=searchSaleInvoice,
                invoiceDateSaleReturn=invoiceDateSaleReturn,
            )
            saleReturnObject.invoiceDateSaleReturn = date.today()
            saleReturnObject.save()
            print("saleReturnObject",saleReturnObject)

            saleReturnItemNameId = request.POST.get('saleReturnItemName')
            saleReturnItem = Egg.objects.get(eggName=saleReturnItemNameId)
            print("-----------------1----------------------")
           
            saleReturnItemNameId = saleReturnItem.id
           
            

            saleReturnItemQuantity = request.POST.getlist('saleReturnItemQuantity')
            saleReturnItemUnitPrice = request.POST.getlist('saleReturnItemUnitPrice')
            saleReturnItemDiscount = request.POST.getlist('saleReturnItemDiscount')

            totalSaleAmountSaleReturn = 0.0
            saleInvoiceAmountSaleReturn = 0.0
            saleInvoiceDiscountSaleReturn = 0.0

            for saleReturnItemNameId,quantity, price, discount,  in zip(saleReturnItemNameIds,
                saleReturnItemQuantity, saleReturnItemUnitPrice, saleReturnItemDiscount
            ):
                saleReturnItemName = next(item for item in saleReturnItemNames if item.id == int(saleReturnItemNameId))
                total_amount = int(quantity) * float(price)
                if discount == '':
                    discount = 0.0
                else:
                    discount = float(discount)
                discounted_amount = total_amount - discount

                # item_name = saleReturnItemNames.get(id=item_id)

                saleReturnItemObject = SaleReturnItem(
                    salereturn=saleReturnObject,
                    saleReturnItemName_id=saleReturnItemNameId,
                    saleReturnItemQuantity=quantity,
                    saleReturnItemUnitPrice=price,
                    saleReturnItemTotalAmount=str(total_amount),
                    saleReturnItemDiscount=discount,
                    saleReturnItemDiscountPrice=str(discounted_amount)
                )
                saleReturnItemObject.save()
                print("saleReturnItemObject",saleReturnItemObject)

                # Adding Item in Egg
                Egg.objects.filter(id=item_name.saleInvoiceItemName.id).update(
                    eggStockQuantity=F('eggStockQuantity') + int(quantity)
                )

                totalSaleAmountSaleReturn += total_amount
                saleInvoiceAmountSaleReturn += discounted_amount
                saleInvoiceDiscountSaleReturn += discount

            saleReturnObject.totalSaleAmountSaleReturn = float(totalSaleAmountSaleReturn)
            saleReturnObject.saleInvoiceAmountSaleReturn = float(saleInvoiceAmountSaleReturn)
            saleReturnObject.saleInvoiceDiscountSaleReturn = float(saleInvoiceDiscountSaleReturn)
            saleReturnObject.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Record Saved Successfully.')
            return redirect('saleReturn')
        except Exception as e:
            messages.error(request, f'Some Error Occurred While Saving Data: {str(e)}')

    saleReturnData = SaleReturn.objects.all()
    results = SaleInvoice.objects.all()
   

    return render(request, 'pages/addSaleReturn.html', {'saleReturnData': saleReturnData, 'results': results})
```

and my html is this

```
<tbody class="table-border-bottom-0" id="item-table-body">
    <tr class="item-row">
        <td>
            <h6 class="item-number"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="saleReturnItemNameId" name="saleReturnItemName"
                class="form-control item-name" placeholder="Search"
                style="height: 40px; width: 150px;"/>
            <!-- <input type="text" id="saleReturnItemNameId" name="saleReturnItemName" class="form-control item-name" placeholder="Search" style="height: 40px; width: 150px;"/>                                                                    -->
        </td>
        <td>
            <input for="saleReturnItemQuantity" type="number" class="form-control item-quantity"
                id="saleReturnItemQuantityId" name="saleReturnItemQuantity"
                style="height: 40px; width: 150px;"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="string" class="form-control item-price" id="saleReturnItemUnitPriceId"
                name="saleReturnItemUnitPrice"/>

        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control item-total-amount"
                id="saleReturnItemTotalAmountId" name="saleReturnItemTotalAmount"/>

        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control item-discount" id="saleReturnItemDiscountId"
                name="saleReturnItemDiscount"/>

        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control item-discounted-amount"
                id="saleReturnItemDiscountPriceId" name="saleReturnItemDiscountPrice"/>

        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The main concept is I'm getting `SaleReturn` items and that items are retrieved from Egg model but I tried hard and I am not getting the egg object.